# How to create a container registry configuration issue exemption when issue id has forward slashes in name?

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry

We have a vulnerability scan configuration issue in our IBM Cloud Container registry that we received an exemption for.  However the issue id contains `/` in the string.  I've tried escaping the slashes, quoting the issue id, sticking in a variable and referencing but I keep getting a generic "An internal server error occurred." message.

Any idea how I can get this exemption created?

issue id: application_configuration:mysql./etc/mysql

ibmcloud cr exemption-add --scope "*" --issue-type configuration  --issue-id "application_configuration:mysql./etc/mysql"

Comment: This is a bug in the way that IBM Cloud container registry handles / characters when applying exemptions.  Thank you for highlighting it, we are just looking into fixing it and hope to do so soon.  Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Thank you...appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in how IBM Cloud container registry handled `/` characters in configuration issue IDs.  The bug has now been fixed so if you retry it should now work as expected with your original command.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention and sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Thank you...appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 0):

For issue id, you need to run the command

```
ibmcloud cr va IMAGENAME
```

For the IMAGENAME, run the below command and check the Repository value

```
ibmcloud cr images
```

You will see the issue ids similar to this

```
Configuration Issues Found
==========================

Configuration Issue ID                     Policy Status   Security Practice                                    How to Resolve
application_configuration:mysql.ssl-key    Active          A setting in /etc/mysql/my.cnf that identifies the   ssl-key is not specified in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
                                                           server private key.
application_configuration:mysql.ssl-ca     Active          A setting in /etc/mysql/my.cnf that specifies the    ssl-ca is not specified in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
                                                           Certificate Authority (CA) certificate.
application_configuration:mysql.ssl-cert   Active          A setting in /etc/mysql/my.cnf that specifies the    ssl-cert is not specified in /etc/mysql/my.cnf
                                                           server public key certificate. This certificate      file.
                                                           can be sent to the client and authenticated
                                                           against its CA certificate.
```